# 'No such module' while referring a pod from Submodule

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, git-submodules, carthage

I have integrated submodule in my swift project and that submodule was earlier using Carthage. Now I moved from Carthage to Cocoapods. But now whenever I am referring ANY pod mentioned in main project or submodule, its throwing below error.

> No such module 'POD_NAME'

Earlier the same error was shown for the submodule, but I added **$(SRCROOT)** in my Framework Search Paths and that error is replaced by the above one.

Comment: Stumbled upon this post. Tried this too, but no avail.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39970273/no-such-module-in-xcode

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cocoapods then after installing the pods build the project once and then try to import the module.

Answer (score 0):

Press Command+Option+Shift+K and then Run your app

go into your build settings and defining the Framework Search Paths to a folder which contains the frameworks in question. If the frameworks are placed in your project directory, simply set the framework search path to $(SRCROOT) and set it to recursive.

or

Make sure that you tried simply skipping import of the framework as it is already added with the bridging header.

Hope this helps

Comment: Used both versions of cleaning. No avail. Quit Xcode and also restarted machine. But failed.

Comment: I explained the full problem scenario. Have already tried all these. Bridging Header is of no use here.