# No such module `Toaster`

Tags: xcode, swift3

I am getting a `No such module Toaster`. I have installed the pod, also after searching on SO, I fixed the `red Pod_Project.Framework` issue. Now its gray. I also verified `Framework Search Path's` and ensured that the Pod in question is `recursive`.

[image: No Such Module]

[image: recursive for Toaster]

I have read thru [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/getting-error-no-such-module-using-xcode-but-the-framework-is-there) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39970273/no-such-module-in-xcode). Ideally I expected that things should have worked by default, just install the Pod and import and it should work. Is this expectation incorrect ? Should I need to change settings everytime I install a pod ?

**EDIT 1**

Also added `Toaster` pod to the `Framework Search Path`
[image: toaster in framework search path]

Still the same `No such module` error on the `import`.

**EDIT 2**

I tried opening the `.xcworkspace`. But same issue again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@siddharth as you mention above is correct. But Linked FrameWorks and Libraries are not in **build Settings**. It is In ***Build Phases***

[image]