# xcode: no such module 'Kingfisher'

Tags: swift, xcode

I want run my app on emulator

But I get this error:

```
no such module 'Kingfisher'
```

pod update, pod install, delete DerivedData folder, restart xcode, use xcworkspace, use xcodeproj and ... not solved my problem!

OS: 11.4
xcode: 12.4

My pod:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

use_frameworks!

target 'Name' do
  pod 'QuickBlox'
  pod 'Quickblox-WebRTC'
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'Kingfisher'
  pod 'NVActivityIndicatorView/Extended'
  pod 'PulsingHalo'
  pod 'ImageScrollView'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No such module ... in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39970273/no-such-module-in-xcode)

Comment: @staticVoidMan i saw this solution. but not work for me

Comment: did you import `KingFisher` in the top of the file before you use it?

Comment: @Yodagama yes of course

Comment: @ParsaNikoo Hm... if you have tried it all then in that case, try this: 1. Clean project || 2. Build || 3. In Xcode project navigator manually navigate & open a few Kingfisher class files || 4. Build & run. (_Step 3 forces Xcode to locate the missing module classes._)

Answer (score 3):

In my case Kingfisher worked with iOS and not with macOS. I used Xcodes package installer and not pod install. In order to fix my "no such module 'Kingfisher'" error for macOS:

1. I had to go to my TARGETS. (on the left side of General/Signing/etc)
2. Click on your macOS target.
3. Click "Build Phases" (2nd to last on the top row)
   [image: Build Phases]
4. Go down to 'Link Binary with libraries.'
5. Click the '+' button and add the Kingfisher library.
   [image: +]

If you have the error in your iOS version then add the library to that target instead. This won't fix everyone's issue, but no other solution I could find online worked and finally after clicking around I found this library was missing and it fixed my error, so I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

please use these commands in order in the project directory
1- pod deintegrate
2- rm podfile.lock
3- pod install
then clean project and build it should work

Answer (score 1):

It happens to me sometimes.

first, clean build and then rebuild the project.
if there is no success try `pod install`, otherwise restart your device.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to podfile helps me

```
post_install do |installer|   
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
  end
end
```